# How to add a new instance of Django model with FileField by ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, forms, modelform, filefield

I'm a Django beginner. I think my problem is trivial but I can't solve it.
I have a model named Document with one FileField:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="documents")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(DocumentCategory)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want to add a new instance to this class by this ModelForm:

```
class DocumentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
```

In views.py I have:

```
def add_document(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return render_to_response('add_document.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render_to_response('add_document.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template for this (i.e. add_document.html):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{{block content %}
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}
<input type="submit" value="Add document" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

In the Admin Interface adding a model to the database is working correctly and adding a file is in "upload_to" localization. My form does not work. When I try to submit a form I get `Filefield error: "This field is required!"` Without FileField in model this works before.
I have Django 1.2.5
I torture with it for 3 days and nothing! I'm desperate. Sorry for my language. Please help!

Comment: That's odd. Can't find any problems other than strange indentation

Comment: Try putting a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` right after your test for the POST method. Then inspect the request object and request.FILES for clues. Good luck.

Comment: Does `{{ form }}` default to `{{ form.as_p }}`?

Answer (score 0):

As it is now, a file is required. Are you trying to save the form without a file?
If you want to make the file optional, you need to define it in this way:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="documents", blank=True, null=True)
```

As a an additional note, the action parameter you have in the form may be incorrect.
It should be an URL; usually in Django you would want to put `"."`, but not a completely empty string (`""`). That said, I do not know if this may be an issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

In you Document model, you have your file set to upload_t0 "documents", but where exactly is upload_to pointed to.

[May be this will help.](http://milindshakya.tumblr.com/post/6468927692/uploading-images-and-files-in-django-forms)